# Saving a marco enabled workbook into a file, need it to be non macro enabled

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to save a file into a location which will then be used to run a report from.
Currently this code is saving the file as a macro enabled worksheet, I need it to be just a .xlsx

```
Sub SaveToDesktop()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        With ActiveWorkbook
            .SaveAs "W:\Logistics\Distribution\Chep\Chep Dehire Master Control\In" & "\" & Format(Now, "hh-nn-ss-dd-mm-yyyy") & " " & ActiveWorkbook.Name
            '.Close
        End With
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Thanks, file saved."
Application.Quit
End Sub
```

Any help or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.workbook.saveas saveAs has a type you can use.  But it will save it without any vba.

Comment: Maybe try `.SaveAs "W:\Logistics\Distribution\Chep\Chep Dehire Master Control\In\" & Format(Now, "hh-nn-ss-dd-mm-yyyy") & " " & Replace(ThisWorkbook.Name, ".xlsm", ".xlsx"), FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook`. Or you do macro recording while you save the workbook as xlsx format manually. Have `application.displayalerts=false" at the beginning of the sub, and just before the end sub, put the same syntax but set it true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys, problem solved!
Read through the guide and worked from karma's suggestion.

```
Sub Saveworkbook()
Dim Path As String
Dim Filename As String
Path = "W:\Logistics\Distribution\Chep\Chep Dehire Master Control\In\"
Filename = ActiveWorkbook.Name & Format(Now, "hh-nn-ss dd-mm-yyyy")
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Path & Filename & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
MsgBox "Thanks, file saved."
Application.Quit
End Sub
```